# Making a timer reset on a light

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm very new to code and want the led.off portion to be extendable. Basically, if I hit the button again before the 10 seconds run out. So if the button is hit before lighting up, there is another 10 second wait, starting at press 2.

```
from time import time, sleep
from signal import pause

led = LED(18) # or whatever pin you've got it on
button = Button(23) # again, adjust as necessary

def light_off_for_10_sec():
    led.off()
    sleep(10)
    led.on()

button.when_pressed = light_off_for_10_sec
```

The 10 second pause before lighting up works great, but here is what I have tried to use to stretch the led.off period.

````
def stretched(values):
    
    when_pressed = 10
    for value in values:
        if value:
            sleep(5)
            pressed = time()
        yield time() - pressed <= 20
        
led.source = stretched(button.pressed)
pause()```
````